# Video created by using separate PNG files as frames is not rendering as expected

Tags: ffmpeg

I am creating a video with ffmpeg by stringing together a bunch of PNG files. The resulting video has horizontal lines running across it and the colors are not accurate. Here's the command I used:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i img%04d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p timer.mp4
```

I am attaching an example of one of the input PNG files and a frame from the video. Can anyone tell what's wrong?

*Input File*
[image: Input File - Screenshot]

*Video Frame*
[image: Video Frame - Screenshot]

Comment: I don't understand why your video player title bar also has this problem.  An issue with your graphics card drivers maybe?

Comment: I'm using macOS v11.6, graphics card Radeon Pro 580X 8 GB

Comment: What video playback software are you using?

Comment: QuickTime Player v10.5